# How to separate JSP from main java project

Tags: java, git, tomcat, gwt

we got existing JAVA web application which contains: GWT module (Administration panel), java servlets with some other services in src path and war folder with JSP's and other static files like: images, css, js.

Web server: Tomcat 7

To build this project we use ant build script. It compiles the project, GWT module and packs it into war file.

Now, I need to separate front-side (JSPs and other static files) from backend (Java servlets and other code on Java) into different git repositories, to allow front-end developers editing it.

The main problem is how to make deployment system on test server. They need to see their changes in real time.

It's impossible to install tomcat and java on each front-developer's machine also they don't know what is Java and how to compile the project, that's why we have test stage with tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to answer this question without knowing the exact architecture and organization matters of the project.

But the fact is, the JSP files are translated and compiled into Servlet during translation stage (back-end side). Therefore, it would be quite hard to isolate JSP files from rest of Java WebApp.

I would consider including part of front-end HTML's into JSP, i.e.:

```
<c:import url="http://example.com/frontend/somepart.html" />
```

Though, you can divide the architecture into:

- BackEnd side: served by Tomcat7 (Java, Servlets, JSP)
- FrontEnd side: served by HTTP WebServer (Apache, nginx, IIS or other) - HTML, CSS, JS

Dynamic parts of the application could be proxied by some url pattern using mod_jk (in Apache) to be handled by Tomcat. It may be accomplished by using GWT in such way (example):

1. Develop Front-End side
2. Include empty DIV with an ID.
3. Attach GWT module in `<script>` tag.
4. GWT modules attached to ID.
5. After module load, every service operation must be proxied to dynamic part. Lets say you backend is under http://example.com/backend so you need to configure the Apache server to serve the content under /backend pattern from Tomcat server.

Let the FrontEnd developers code the front-end (html, css, js files) and make deployments on HTTP server without interferring with Back-End development. BackEnd developers could easily deliver their work into Tomcat servers.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Sorry for late approve, yeah we did it in similar way (we were serving html content on another web server).

Comment: Cool, if You are satisfied with my answer Please approve it. Thx.